# Problems navigating to URL like "/annotationsList/:id"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate from a List of annotations to an concrete Annotation using a Link from React Router. But It didn't render the component.

So, I have an AnnotationList in where I have all the annotations. Each annotation have a "". In my Container.js I have declared the Route like this:

```
<Route path="/annotationList/annView/:id" component={annView} />
```

And in the same Container I have the component annView:

```
const annView = ({ match }) => {
    const { id } = match.params;
    console.log(id);
    return(
        <AnnotationView id={id} />
    )
}
```

When I click on the Link, the URL change to the correct one, but it didn't render anything. What Am I doing wrong?

I paste the complete code of these two js files if it helps.

Container.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductList from './List/ProductList';
import CustomersList from './List/CustomersList';
import AppointmentsList from './List/AppointmentsList';
import AnnotationList from './List/AnnotationList';
import AddProduct from './Post/AddProduct';
import '../styles/App.css';
import AnnotationView from './Item/AnnotationView';

function Container({ location }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch location={location}>
                <Route path="/productsList" component={ProductList} />
                <Route path="/customersList" component={CustomersList} />
                <Route path="/appointmentsList" component={AppointmentsList} />
                <Route path="/annotationList" component={AnnotationList} />
                <Route path="/annotationList/annView/:id" component={annView} />
                <Route path="/addProduct" component={AddProduct} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}

const annView = ({ match }) => {
    const { id } = match.params;
    console.log(id);
    return(
        <AnnotationView id={id} />
    )
}

export default withRouter(Container);
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import AnnotationView from '../Item/AnnotationView';

class AnnotationList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            annotations: [],
            isLoading: false
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/annotations')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({annotations: data, isLoading: false}));
    }

    render() {
        const { annotations, isLoading } = this.state;

        if(isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <h2>Anotaciones</h2>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="date"/>
                </div>
                <Table>
                    {annotations.map((ann) =>
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <Link to={`/annotationsList/annView/${ann.id}`}>
                                    <th>{ann.name}</th>
                                </Link>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{ann.text}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AnnotationList;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `exact` like this `<Route exact path="/annotationList" component={AnnotationList} />` ?

Comment: Try to switch the annotationsList routes:

`<Route path="/annotationList/annView/:id" component={annView} />
<Route path="/annotationList" component={AnnotationList} />
`


console.log in annView is printing the value correctly?

Comment: Its not printing anything, i suppose i'm not calling it correctly. I tried both things, but still remains the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Link` component.

You're trying to match this route 
`<Route path="/annotationList/annView/:id" component={annView} />`

but your `Link` has `annotations` with an **s** 
`/annotationsList/annView/anythingHere`

You have to change your `Link` Component to this:

```
<Link to={`/annotationList/annView/${ann.id}`}>
  <th>{ann.name}</th>
</Link>
```

**Note:** I would still recommend that every time you have similar routes you use `exact` on at least 1 of them to let React Router know how to differentiate between the routes.

```
function Container({ location }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch location={location}>
                <Route path="/productsList" component={ProductList} />
                <Route path="/customersList" component={CustomersList} />
                <Route path="/appointmentsList" component={AppointmentsList} />
                <Route exact path="/annotationList" component={AnnotationList} />
                <Route path="/annotationList/annView/:id" component={annView} />
                <Route path="/addProduct" component={AddProduct} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I feel embarrased now... So many hours in this. Also, I will start using exact from now on. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidVillanuevaGarcía It happens to all of us. Glad to help!